# Rails 3 Sort Scope By Self-Accumulated Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, count, scope, sql-order-by

So I have a Results table for a Tournament where multiple matches might occur with the same player.

So some sample data might be:

Results

```
Player_ID | Match_ID|Win|Elapsed_Time|etc..
1         |    1    |T  | 1:00       |etc..
2         |    1    |F  | 1:00       |etc..
1         |    2    |T  | 3:00       |etc..
3         |    2    |F  | 3:00       |etc..
```

I want to prepare a scope that will count the Win fields that are set to True for each Player and and group by that count field.

So pseudo-code would be something like...

scope :most_wins, :all, :order_by => "Count(Player Wins)"

Is this even possible or should I re-think my database structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: [Named Scopes Are Dead](http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/)

I suggest you do the following:

```
class Players < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  def self.with_win_count
    #inner join if you want to filter out those who doesn't have any match, otherwise is should be left outer 
    joins("inner join (select Player_ID, count(Match_ID) as win_count from Results where Win = true group by Player_ID) t on (t.Player_ID = Player.ID)")
  end
end

#somewhere in controller you would do
best_players = Player.with_win_count.where("win_count > ?", [10]).order("win_count DESC")
```

In case you want it to be in Results table:

```
class Results < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  def self.with_win_count
    joins("inner join (select Player_ID, count(Match_ID) as win_count from Results where Win = true group by Player_ID) t on (t.Player_ID = Results.Player_ID)")
  end
end
```

this gonna work but I find it a little bit ugly.

And if you want conditional count in the nested query the simple way would be:

```
class Players < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  def self.with_match_count(conditions)
    #inner join if you want to filter out those who doesn't have any match, otherwise is should be left outer 
    joins("inner join (select Player_ID, count(Match_ID) as match_count from Results where #{conditions} group by Player_ID) t on (t.Player_ID = Player.ID)")
  end
end
some_players = Player.with_match_count("Win = true").where("match_count > ?", [10]).order("match_count DESC")
```

**!!!** Please note that it is prone to SQL injections if `conditions` argument is going to be directly built of user input.

Comment: HI Forker, thanks for filling me in on scopes in Rails 3. The code you provided almost works, but I had to change the def with_win_count to self.with_win_count or else it would give the undefined method for class error.

Comment: Is there any way to keep this within the scope of only the Results table? The reason I ask is because I'm using this in a dynamic query that is being built and there are additional fields from the Results table that I would like to filter. Something like:       `query = Player.with_win_count.where(..........) query = query.where(results_field = ....) if condition` of course, the Player table is the parent of Results

Comment: I tried simply adding the additional Results fields I wanted to the select in the with_win_count and the group by but that doesn't seem to work correctly

Comment: Great choice! However, I think I understood your question and the last snippet I added should help. So with `with_match_count` you'll be able to calculate wins, defeats and other match counts.

Comment: Hey Forker thanks again for you help that worked perfect for me. I think I prefer the idea of specifying the conditional count in the controller as per your first example for better re-use and also the fact that we can protect against SQL injections.